# Actions on Google not recognized by Google Home speaker. Online Simulator is working

Tags: actions-on-google

I accidentially moved to the new Actions on Google dashboard. Since then my project does not really work anymore.

I changed the json structure and uploaded a new version that is now running fine on the simulator.

Unfortunately, my Google Home device is not recognizing that such an action exists. This was working before when using the old actions on google api.

Ciao
Fabio

Comment: Can you clarify if this is an app that is already published, or one that you are testing.

Comment: Hey, I guess from your name that you're in Italy. Same here, how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The invocation name has changed when testing apps on the Google Home device.

You should now say

> Talk to my test app